# c# how to define class object inside other method

Tags: c#, class

in my code, i have class:

```
public class letterCount
        {
            public int count;
            public letter(int count) 
              {
               this.count = count;
              }
    }
```

then i want to do:

```
letterCount a = new letterCount(0);
```

in one function, and

```
a.count++;
```

in another , but it keeps erroring me that: The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

both functions are public void type
What can i do?
Reason i want definition (or initialization? idk how to call it, sry) in another function is, because i will have like 40 class definitions, so i thought it would be more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
private letterCount a = null;
```

out of your methods, and

```
a = new letterCount(0);
```

inside the method where actually is.
Just be careful that if the second method is called before the first you'll get an error (because a is not instantiated). To avoid this (unless there's a particular reason for instantiating it only when the first method is called) you could do

```
private letterCount a = new letterCount(0);
```

directly, out of both methods.

**EDIT:**

Ok then after the comments, I'd suggest a different approach, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = letterCounter("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private const string charsToBeCounted = "abcdefghikjlmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // ABCDEFGHIKJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ capital letters not needed converting the string to lowercase

        public static Dictionary<char, int> letterCounter(string word)
        {
            var ret = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            word = word.ToLower();
            foreach (char ch in word)
            {
                if (charsToBeCounted.Contains(ch))
                {
                    if (ret.ContainsKey(ch))
                        ret[ch]++;
                    else
                        ret[ch] = 1;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

the function returns a dictionary where letters are the keys and counters are the values. No need for all those objects.

**EDIT2:**

To use the result do like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = letterCounter(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        foreach(char c in d.Keys)
        {
             textBox2.Text += d[c].ToString() + " ";
        }
    }
```

**EDIT3:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = letterCounter("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class letter
        {
            public int count;
            public string stringValue;
        }

        private const string charsToBeCounted = "abcdefghikjlmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // ABCDEFGHIKJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ capital letters not needed converting the string to lowercase

        public static Dictionary<char, letter> letterCounter(string word)
        {
            var ret = new Dictionary<char, letter>();
            word = word.ToLower();
            foreach (char ch in word)
            {
                if (charsToBeCounted.Contains(ch))
                {
                    letter l = null;
                    if (ret.ContainsKey(ch))
                        l = ret[ch];
                    else
                    {
                        l = new letter();
                        ret.Add(ch, l);
                    }
                    l.count++;
                    l.stringValue = "Any value you want";
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

then your button becomes:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = letterCounter(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        foreach(char c in d.Keys)
        {
             textBox2.Text += d[c].count.ToString() + " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @urgot Please post full code then. Actually the purpose of the code itself is unclear.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jpqdJMdZ
the program should do this: count occurrence of letters in input string ,but  i also need to reset counters everytime i press button1

Comment: Then you have a text and you just want to count the occurrencies of any letter in the text, counting again every time you click the button?

Comment: yeah, actually thats the first part,the second part will be try to code huffman coding based on this values

Comment: @leonardo_spina thanks, but is it possible to add another var similar to counter- like string binaryRepresentation, where will be binary representation of value, and then use this binary value in code and work with it? also, i hope there is no problem with usage of win form app instead of your  console

Comment: I made a console application because it's quicker to test (just copy and paste into VS to see how it works. You can just get the part you're interested in and copy into your code. For the string representation of values I'd say a simple ".ToString()" should work.

Comment: thanks, but can i store one more information? not only counter value, but also binary value (this will be assigned manually based on occurrence)
(dictionaries are totally new for me)
*edit-technically- is it posible to assign more values to one key?

Comment: Look at Edit3, value now is your class, so you can add any property you want and carry any value you want.

Comment: sry, i dont know what you mean, how can i do it?